# Remove string after predefined string

Tags: javascript, replace

I am pulling content from an RSS feed, before using jquery to format and edit the rss feed (string) that is returned. I am using `replace` to replace strings and characters like so:

```
var spanish = $("#wod a").text();
var newspan = spanish.replace("=","-");
$("#wod a").text(newspan);
```

This works great. I am also trying to remove all text after a certain point. Similar to truncation, I would like to hide all text starting from the word "Example".

In this particular RSS feed, the word example is in every feed. I would like to hide `"example"` and all text the follows that word. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Though there is not enough jQuery, you even don't need it to remove everything after a certain word in the given string. The first approach is to use `substring`:

```
var new_str = str.substring(0, str.indexOf("Example"));
```

The second is a trick with `split`:

```
var new_str = str.split("Example")[0];
```

Comment: How would I wrap example and everything after that in a div?

Comment: @JCHASE11 Something like that: `$("div").text(function(i, val) { return val.split("Example")[0]; });`.

Comment: how do i catch list of words ? For example, remove all strings after the words "all", "but", "and" ?

Comment: @Gel Not sure I understand. You can create a new question and provide an extended example in the description. Somebody will help you to find a solution.

Comment: For example, A user entered a phrase `"what is the price of gas in Japan ?"` or the user might ask `"what is the price of oil at the early part of the year? "` How do I make it so that all I capture is `what is the price of gas`  and `what is the price of oil?` respectively

Answer (score 13):

If you also want to keep "Example" and just remove everything *after* that particular word, you can do:

```
var str = "aaaa1111?bbb&222:Example=123456",
    newStr = str.substring(0, str.indexOf('Example') + 'Example'.length);

// will output: aaaa1111?bbb&222:Example
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

jQuery isn't intended for string manipulation, you should use [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) for that:

```
newspan = newspan.replace(/example.*$/i, "");
```

The [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts a regular expression, so in this case I've used `/example.*$/i` which does a case-insensitive match against the word "example" followed by zero or more of any other characters to the end of the string and replaces them with an empty string.

Comment: I like this solution because it's case-insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to hide all text starting from the word "Example"

A solution that uses the simpler replace WITH backreferences so as to "hide" everything starting with the word Example but keeping the stuff before it.

```
var str = "my house example is bad"
str.replace(/(.*?) example.*/i, "$1")     // returns "my house"
// case insensitive. also note the space before example because you 
// probably want to throw that out.
```